# MAX function is causing performance issue in select clause oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

We have one query which is causing performance issue because of  in select cause in case statement.Without that part,full query completing in 20 sec and with this one query took 3 minutes of time.Any way how we can improve the performance of the select below query

```
(SELECT MAX (ordered_item)
FROM apps.oe_order_lines_all ool, APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B b
WHERE ool.ato_line_id = oola.line_id
AND ool.inventory_item_id = b.inventory_item_id
AND ool.ship_from_org_id = b.organization_id
AND b.item_type = 'CONFIGURED_ITEM'
AND ool.FLOW_STATUS_CODE <> 'CANCELLED')
```

As it is self join with ool and if i remove that join it is taking time

```
> SELECT  
>        DISTINCT
>         hzp.PARTY_NAME,
>               CASE
>            WHEN b.item_type = 'ATO'
>            THEN
>                (SELECT MAX (ordered_item)
>                   FROM apps.oe_order_lines_all ool, APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B b
>                  WHERE     ool.ato_line_id = oola.line_id
>                        AND ool.inventory_item_id = b.inventory_item_id
>                        AND ool.ship_from_org_id = b.organization_id
>                        AND b.item_type = 'CONFIGURED_ITEM'
>                        AND ool.FLOW_STATUS_CODE <> 'CANCELLED')
>            ELSE
>                NULL
>        END
>            ato_configured_item   FROM APPS.OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL    ooha,
>        APPS.OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL      oola,
>        APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B      b,
>        APPS.MTL_PARAMETERS          mp,
>        APPS.OE_HOLD_DEFINITIONS     ohd,
>        APPS.OE_HOLD_SOURCES_ALL     ohsa,
>        APPS.OE_ORDER_HOLDS_ALL      ooha1,
>        APPS.FND_USER                fu,
>        APPS.HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL   hzcsu,
>        APPS.HZ_CUST_ACCT_SITES_ALL  hzcas,
>        APPS.HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS        hzca,
>        APPS.HZ_PARTIES              hzp,-----------
>        APPS.HZ_PARTY_SITES          hzps  WHERE     ooha.HEADER_ID = oola.HEADER_ID 
>        AND ooha.ORG_ID = oola.ORG_ID 
>        AND oola.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = b.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID 
>        AND b.ORGANIZATION_ID = mp.ORGANIZATION_ID 
>        AND oola.SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID = mp.ORGANIZATION_ID 
>        AND ooha.HEADER_ID = ooha1.HEADER_ID
>        AND oola.LINE_ID = ooha1.LINE_ID
>        AND ooha1.HOLD_SOURCE_ID = ohsa.HOLD_SOURCE_ID
>        AND ohsa.HOLD_ID = ohd.HOLD_ID
>        AND b.CREATED_BY = fu.USER_ID
>        AND hzcsu.SITE_USE_ID = ooha.INVOICE_TO_ORG_ID
>        AND hzcas.CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID = hzcsu.CUST_ACCT_SITE_ID
>        AND hzca.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID = hzcas.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID
>        AND hzp.PARTY_ID = hzca.PARTY_ID
>        AND hzps.PARTY_SITE_ID = hzcas.PARTY_SITE_ID
>        AND oola.ITEM_TYPE_CODE IN ('MODEL', 'STANDARD', NULL) --Configured Items and Parts
>        AND ooha1.RELEASED_FLAG IN ('N', NULL)              --Active holds only
>        AND ooha.org_id IN ('1703')                            --1703 = Valves
>       AND oola.FLOW_STATUS_CODE NOT IN ('CLOSED', 'CANCELLED')
>        AND ooha.FLOW_STATUS_CODE NOT IN ('CLOSED', 'CANCELLED') 
>        AND oola.open_flag IN ('Y', NULL)          
>        AND mp.ORGANIZATION_CODE IN ('FIM'
>                                    )
```

Execution plan

We have one query which is causing performance issue because of MAX (ordered_item) in select cause in case statement.Without that part query completing in 20 sec and with this one query took 3 minutes of time.Any way to handle this MAX so performance can improve.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                  | Name                     | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                           |                          |        |       |   197K(100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                            |                          |      1 |    62 |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                             |                          |        |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                            |                          |     42 |  2604 |   145   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL       |     42 |  1722 |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                      | OE_ORDER_LINES_N17       |     45 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                      | MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B_U1    |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B       |      1 |    21 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |  SORT AGGREGATE                            |                          |      1 |   210 |            |          |
|   9 |   NESTED LOOPS                             |                          |      1 |   210 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |    NESTED LOOPS                            |                          |      1 |   162 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |     NESTED LOOPS                           |                          |      1 |    82 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |      NESTED LOOPS                          |                          |      1 |    41 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_U1   |      1 |    22 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_B      |      1 |    19 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_B_U1   |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 16 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_TL     |      1 |    41 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_TL_U1  |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 18 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | MTL_CATEGORIES_B         |      1 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | MTL_CATEGORIES_B_U1      |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                        | FND_LOOKUP_VALUES_U1     |      1 |    48 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |  SORT AGGREGATE                            |                          |      1 |   210 |            |          |
|  22 |   NESTED LOOPS                             |                          |      1 |   210 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |    NESTED LOOPS                            |                          |      1 |   162 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |     NESTED LOOPS                           |                          |      1 |    82 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  25 |      NESTED LOOPS                          |                          |      1 |    41 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 26 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_U1   |      1 |    22 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  27 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_B      |      1 |    19 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 28 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_B_U1   |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 29 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_TL     |      1 |    41 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 30 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_TL_U1  |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 31 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | MTL_CATEGORIES_B         |      1 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 32 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | MTL_CATEGORIES_B_U1      |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                        | FND_LOOKUP_VALUES_U1     |      1 |    48 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  34 |  SORT AGGREGATE                            |                          |      1 |   210 |            |          |
|  35 |   NESTED LOOPS                             |                          |      1 |   210 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  36 |    NESTED LOOPS                            |                          |      1 |   162 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  37 |     NESTED LOOPS                           |                          |      1 |    82 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  38 |      NESTED LOOPS                          |                          |      1 |    41 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 39 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_U1   |      1 |    22 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  40 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_B      |      1 |    19 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 41 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_B_U1   |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 42 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_TL     |      1 |    41 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 43 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | MTL_CATEGORY_SETS_TL_U1  |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 44 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | MTL_CATEGORIES_B         |      1 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 45 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | MTL_CATEGORIES_B_U1      |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 46 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                        | FND_LOOKUP_VALUES_U1     |      1 |    48 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  47 |  HASH UNIQUE                               |                          |      1 |   412 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  48 |   NESTED LOOPS                             |                          |        |       |            |          |
|  49 |    NESTED LOOPS                            |                          |      1 |   412 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  50 |     NESTED LOOPS                           |                          |      1 |   374 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  51 |      NESTED LOOPS                          |                          |      1 |   362 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  52 |       NESTED LOOPS                         |                          |      1 |   356 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  53 |        NESTED LOOPS                        |                          |      1 |   337 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  54 |         NESTED LOOPS                       |                          |      1 |   332 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  55 |          NESTED LOOPS                      |                          |      1 |   287 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  56 |           NESTED LOOPS                     |                          |      1 |   266 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  57 |            NESTED LOOPS                    |                          |      1 |   252 |   197K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  58 |             NESTED LOOPS                   |                          |    710 |   159K|   195K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  59 |              NESTED LOOPS                  |                          |    710 |   124K|   194K  (1)| 00:00:08 |
|  60 |               NESTED LOOPS                 |                          |  40073 |  4461K| 75450   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|* 61 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL           | MTL_PARAMETERS           |     32 |   288 |    20   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  62 |                INLIST ITERATOR             |                          |        |       |            |          |
|* 63 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL       |   1252 |   128K|  3362   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 64 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN          | OE_ORDER_LINES_X101      |  10395 |       |   161   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  65 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B       |      1 |    66 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 66 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B_U1    |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 67 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL     |      1 |    50 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 68 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | OE_ORDER_HEADERS_U1      |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 69 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | OE_ORDER_HOLDS_ALL       |      1 |    22 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 70 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN              | OE_ORDER_HOLDS_ALL_N2    |      3 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  71 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_ALL    |      1 |    14 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 72 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | HZ_CUST_SITE_USES_U1     |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  73 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | OE_HOLD_SOURCES_ALL      |      1 |    21 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 74 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | OE_HOLD_SOURCES_U1       |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 75 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | OE_HOLD_DEFINITIONS      |      1 |    45 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 76 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | OE_HOLDS_U1              |      1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|* 77 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | FND_USER_U1              |      1 |     5 |     0   (0)|          |
|  78 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | HZ_CUST_ACCT_SITES_ALL   |      1 |    19 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 79 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | HZ_CUST_ACCT_SITES_U1    |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 80 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | HZ_PARTY_SITES_U1        |      1 |     6 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 81 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                      | XXAR_HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS_N2 |      1 |    12 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 82 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                      | HZ_PARTIES_U1            |      1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  83 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | HZ_PARTIES               |      1 |    38 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Comment: do you have an execution plan available?  check for indexing on all WHERE conditions

Comment: Issue is with select statement MAX condition case statement

Comment: Why no turn the select max into a subquery factoring. Also add ool.ato_line_id to the select part and group by it. Then select from the subquery and filter by oola.line_id

Comment: Do i need to do over partition by also??

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, that is easier to read and debug.

Comment: @TheImpaler I imagine the query comes from existing legacy code; it isn't always possible to rewrite a query due to other constraints, e.g. testing, risk, etc. I'm sure if the OP was writing a new query, they'd use ANSI to do so.

Comment: @JackShadow please edit your question to add in the execution plan for this query. I don't doubt that the issue is the MAX subquery, but without the execution plan, we can't tell you if, for example, adding indexes may help or not

Comment: @JackShadow:Added execution plan

Comment: Even without MAX function also this sql is taking time.Still the issue is with that part,buw now if i remove max also and i ran that part commenting   AND ool.ato_line_id = oola.line_id it is taking more time

Comment: @JackShadow: Are your table statistics up to date ?

Comment: @jackshadow:Yesstats are up to date and last analyzed was last week on all the table.

Comment: @JackShadow It would be helpful if the execution plan included both the estimated and the *actual* values. If the results included the "A-Time" instead of just the "E-Time", it might be possible to identify which of the 83 operations are consuming the time. With the "A-Rows" instead of just the "E-Rows", it may be possible to tell where Oracle's cardinality estimate goes wrong, which is the root of many performance problems. See [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_xplan#gather_plan_statistics_hint) for an example of generating the "actual" numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this:

```
 with ord_items as (
    SELECT MAX (ordered_item) moi, ool.ato_line_id
    FROM apps.oe_order_lines_all ool, APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B b
    WHERE ool.inventory_item_id = b.inventory_item_id
    AND ool.ship_from_org_id = b.organization_id
    AND b.item_type = 'CONFIGURED_ITEM'
    AND ool.FLOW_STATUS_CODE <> 'CANCELLED'
    group by ool.ato_line_id)
SELECT  
    DISTINCT
     hzp.PARTY_NAME,
           CASE
        WHEN b.item_type = 'ATO'
        THEN
            (select ois.moi from ord_items ois where ois.ato_line_id = oola.line_id)
        ELSE
            NULL
    END
        ato_configured_item   FROM  ....
```

Comment: It didn't work as still performance issue there